# Can't display XY data in MXD on ArcGIS Desktop- onEnable error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, convert, error, excel, xy

When using Display XY data function on imported excel into MXD I get this error:

[image]

and if I click on "ok" then I get this message:

[image]

and the MXD get stuck and I must shut down the ArcGIS program. I know this solution http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/data-source-does-not-have-an-oid-field.htm

but I don't understand what has changed from yesterday? by routine I always managed to convert Excel file into shapefile with Display XY data function

I work on this Excel, all the field are regular- as always:

[image]

Comment: Did you check that your excel column header are not the problem (like having space or special character, starting with number, being reserved word, ....)

Comment: i edit the question.

Comment: The 1st screenshot is not an error, it's just to  remind you that the imported Excel data cannot be edited or related to other data (because an Excel sheet does not have the concept of an ObjectID field). You can however still display or export the data to other formats. I don't know about the 2nd screenshot, do you have any add-ins installed in ArcMap?

Comment: i will check if i add addin

Comment: i removed all addin and , still i have this problem